# Extract keys for a given number of identifiers from a string and form a hash map/object using regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate a pandas formula that is getting inputted to my frontend by the end-user:

[image]

This along with a dummy data containing csv is sent to the backend where these formulaes are parsed using eval function in a try-catch block and if the system catches any error a response is returned accordingly.

What I am interested in doing is from an input string that looks something like this:

`"csv['Date']+env['filename']+csv['Spend']"`

and an array that looks something like this:

`const locatedDfs = ['csv','env']`

I want to create a dictionary/object that looks something like this:

```
{
    csv: {Date:'',Spend:''},
    env: {filename: ''}
}
```

What the above function does is basically scans the entire string with respect to the `locatedDfs` array/list and checks if there are any keys for the same and if a key exists, then it initializes that pair with an empty string.

Comment: I want to implement it with regex and am not sure how to dynamically create an expression for the same, additionally, I am also looking if there's a third-party library that could be more efficient and optimized than re-inventing everything from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression that separates the matching results in two groups, the key and the value

```js
const data = "csv['Date']+env['filename']+csv['Spend']+test['123_abc']";
const locatedDfs = ['csv','env'];

// 1. Create a regex that matches: $1['$2']
const regex = /(\w+)\[\'(\w+)\'\]/gm;
// 2. Create an empty object to store the results.
const result = {};
// Start searching the regex in the data
let match = regex.exec(data);

do {
    // The match will return an array with 3 values
    //
    // [0] => The complete match, for example: csv['Date']
    // [1] => The first match group (\w+) or $1: csv
    // [2] => The second match group ['(\w+)'] or $2: Date
    //
    // Using array destruction we can store it as variables 
    const [, key, value] = match;
    // Store the matched values into the result.
    result[key] = { ...(result[key] || {}), [value]: '' };
} while ((match = regex.exec(data)) !== null) // Continue iterating until there's no more matches.

const expectedResult = locatedDfs.reduce((returnObj, current) => ({ ...returnObj, [current]: result[current] }), {});

console.log(expectedResult);
```